# Stream from Android to Adobe Media Server

Tags: android, stream, rtmp

I am working on a solution that would allow android phone to stream to adobe media server a live stream. The phone will start recording and instantly it will broadcast it to the server.

From what I have read so far, Adobe expects RTMP or HTTP.

Does anyone have a starter tip to implement those protocols. Remember, I am looking for publishing mechanism not consuming. This means the phone will act as the publisher.

Thanks,

We will be using Android 3.0+.

Thanks,